# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-rcp, jfreechart, e4

I am using eclipse e4 rcp application and am trying to use JfreeChart in it. So I have added the jcommon-1.0.16.jar,jfreechart-1.0.14.jar, jfreechart-1.0.14-experimental.jar and jfreechart-1.0.14-swt.jar in external jar file in Build path. I am getting the following error when I am running the application

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset 
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
.............
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset cannot be found by com.xyz.project_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
```

Can anyone please suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Do you have a plugin, which contains the Jfreechart jars, and are you trying to use XYDataset outside this plugin (the exception suggests that you are injecting a XYDataset into some method). If so you need to export the jfreechart classes and the other plugin needs to depend on the plugin exporting the jfreechart classes. (Remark: I am using jfreechart in an Eclipse E4 rich client application and it works)

Comment: No. I am not using plugin.  I have just downloaded these jars and added it in the build path. Do I have to make any other changes?

Comment: The usual method is to add the jars to the plugin (plugin.xml / manifest). This information is used to configure the OSGi class loading mechanism. The build path is only used at build time.

Answer (score 1):

There might be another jar that is missing. You need to check whether all jars are present in the Eclipse build path of your project.

Are you running the application from outside Eclipse IDE, on the command line? 
If yes, then set classpath

```
SET CLASSPATH=pathtojar1;pathtojar2
```

before you execute your program.

Or specify classpath on the command itself

```
java -cp pathtojar1;pathtojar2;yourClassesFolderOrYourJar [ yourclassname or -jar yourjarname]
```

Comment: I am running the application inside Eclipse. Do I hav to add it inside the RunConfigurations->Program arguments? If so there are already some arguments present in it. DO I have to append the command that u have mentioned in Program arguments ? P.S:I am new to eclipse

Comment: [[ Do I hav to add it inside the RunConfigurations->Program arguments? ]] - I do not think so. Do try running from the command line by specifing classpaths. I updated my answer slightly. include your own classes folder in the classpath too.  Adding jars to your Project >Rightclick>Properties>Java Build Path should work. Eclipse adds the build path jars to your classpath when it executes a Java program from within. Or have they changed something in a new version for external jars ??

Comment: do let me know if it helps. I am also keen to know what the pitfall was :-)

Comment: I have created the lib folder and I have put all the jars inside the lib folder and then I have added jars in the buildpath. Now the problem is solved.

Comment: Ohh well,, i learnt something about eclipse. jars added as external jars in the build path - are not added to classpath when running. I do not ever recall running into problems when I have added to external jars. Strange. Maybe they changed something in a newer Eclipse version!